# How to disable the default woocommerce my account link?

Tags: wordpress

I install woocommerce custom my account page plugin, but it show double menu in my account page

https://prnt.sc/ts2tp3

How to disable the default left menu?  And I use the flatsome theme.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any cache plugin installed?

If yes, try clearing your cache.
If no, try setting a new page as your woocommerce account page

Answer (score 1):

In flatsome, you simply goto the page editor (select your 'my account' page), and through ux builder on the left side select the page template and change it to anything other than the 'woocommerce my account' template.